# Is there a list of named arguments that have changed in siunitx v3?

Tags: siunitx

I'm trying to update and compile some old documents, and I've run into an error on the line following `\RequirePackage[siunitx]` (`! Undefined Control Sequence. \@nnil -> \@nil` on another `\RequirePackage`).  It appears that `scientific-notation=true` doesn't work any more (`exponent-mode=scientific` would appear to be the replacement), and I could simply delete all the `table`... options.

So I've fixed it for now, but is there a list of removed options and their equivalents to help with migrating from V2 to V3? This is a thoroughly-documented package, and I've read the change-notes on CTAN, so I know the rationale behind the changes and I know that the old term isn't referenced in the latest manual. I also know that I could force V2 but the current document is a presentation I'm likely to keep coming back to so I'd like to migrate to the current version.

It's a bit strange.  The following MWE shows the error in TeX Live 2021:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[number-unit-product = \text{~}]{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

but a longer document with the same option (as the last in a list) doesn't.  Copying that same  list into my minimal file does.

I've `tlmgr update --all` with no effect on the error.

Updating that option to `[product-symbol=~]` seems to fix it, while `[product-symbol=\text{~}]` doesn't (and is probably unnecessary though I had reasons at the time around occasionally but inconsistently using siunitx in maths mode).  Even `[number-unit-product=~]` doesn't give an error any more, though I could have sworn it did before.

I'd still like (to generate) a list of obsolete options to avoid unexpected output even in the absence of errors

Comment: The full list is in the [ChangeLog](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/compare/v2.8e...v3.0.0), and there is code detail in the emulation sources. _However_, you shouldn't get an uncontrolled error if you use an removed option, so something else is going on. Can you include an example showing the issue?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133554/discussion-on-question-by-chris-h-is-there-a-list-of-named-arguments-that-have-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [ChangeLog for `siunitx`](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) has details of this type. In particularly, the list of every option added/deprecated/removed between v2.8e and v3.0.0 is [available](https://github.com/josephwright/siunitx/compare/v2.8e...v3.0.0), and should be comprehensive. (The ChangeLog is also available using `texdoc`, you'll just need to pass the `-l` option then pick the correct entry.) The ChangeLog should be accurate for all of the v2 changes as well as those in v3: I imported all of the data that was in the sources (`\changes`) in the v2 `.dtx` file.

If there are any omissions, please report them and I will seek to address them. In particular, while it's relatively easy to check the Git log for changes between minor releases of the same major release, the code was re-written between v1 and v2, and between v2 and v3, so these have essentially separate histories.

Comment: As this is definitive, I've skipped my normal practice of waiting 24 hours before accepting